# How to capture jenkins job abort action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

1. Job is started from jenkins
2. Server creates a TCPIP communication and talk with other server
3. Creates a dynamic job id
4. Manual job abort , just closes the tcpip communication, instead I want to kill the process using the dynamically generated job id and then close the tcpip communication.

I want to capture the job abort event from jenkins, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `currentBuild.currentResult` variable to catch aborted state.

```
if (currentBuild.currentResult == 'ABORTED') {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Just place this at the end of the script, or in `finally` block in `try/catch/finally`.